# What is theoretical maximum of TCP traffic over GigaEthernet?

Tags: tcp, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

What is theoretical maximum of TCP traffic over GigaEthernet ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check [Max Ethernet and TCP Throughput](http://www.babinszki.com/Networking/Max-Ethernet-and-TCP-Throughput.html)

Okay, check [Protocol Overhead](http://sd.wareonearth.com/~phil/net/overhead/). This one has information about theoretical speed.

```
Theoretical maximum UDP throughput on GigE using jumbo frames:
(9000-20-8)/(9000+14+4+7+1+12)*1000000000/1000000 = 992.697 Mbps 
Theoretical maximum TCP throughput on GigE without using jumbo frames:
(1500-20-20-12)/(1500+14+4+7+1+12)*1000000000/1000000 = 941.482 Mbps    
Theoretical maximum UDP throughput on GigE without using jumbo frames:
(1500-20-8)/(1500+14+4+7+1+12)*1000000000/1000000 = 957.087 Mbps
```